# how to add a delay when you tap when firing a bullet on my game

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, sprite-kit

i need help on this issue, in my game when a node is tapped a bullet is fired, but the problem is that i can tap continually and a lot of bullets fire, i would like to add some kind of delay to the shot.

here is my touches began code

```
    for touch: AnyObject in touches{
        let pointOfTouch = touch.location(in:self)

        if player1.contains(pointOfTouch) {
            fireBullet1()
        }

        if player2.contains(pointOfTouch) {
            fireBullet2()
        }

        if player3.contains(pointOfTouch) {
            fireBullet3()
        }
    }
  }
}
func fireBullet1() {

    let bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b")
    bullet.position = player1.position
    bullet.zPosition = 1
    self.addChild(bullet)

    let moveBullet = SKAction.moveTo(y: self.size.height + bullet.size.height, duration: 1)
    let deleteBullet = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let bulletSequence = SKAction.sequence([moveBullet, deleteBullet])
    bullet.run(bulletSequence)



}

func fireBullet2 () {

    let bullet2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b")
    bullet2.position = player2.position
    bullet2.zPosition = 1
    self.addChild(bullet2)

    let moveBullet = SKAction.moveTo(y: self.size.height + bullet2.size.height, duration: 1)
    let deleteBullet = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let bulletSequence = SKAction.sequence([moveBullet, deleteBullet])
    bullet2.run(bulletSequence)





}

func fireBullet3() {

    let bullet3 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b")
    bullet3.position = player3.position
    bullet3.zPosition = 1
    self.addChild(bullet3)


    let moveBullet = SKAction.moveTo(y: self.size.height + bullet3.size.height, duration: 1)
    let deleteBullet = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let bulletSequence = SKAction.sequence([moveBullet, deleteBullet])
    bullet3.run(bulletSequence)



}
```

Comment: You can use **[`Timers`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/timer)**

Comment: Could you show me a code example on how I could add this to the game?

Comment: See DuncanC's answer. It is exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare flags to disable multiple firing immediatly

```
let minFireDelay = 0.5

var allowsFire1 = true
var allowsFire2 = true
var allowsFire3 = true
```

Update touches began

```
for touch: AnyObject in touches {

    let pointOfTouch = touch.location(in:self)

    if allowsFire1 && player1.contains(pointOfTouch) {
        fireBullet1()
        // disable firing temporarily
        allowsFire1 = false
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + minFireDelay) { 
           allowsFire1 = true
        }
    }

    if allowsFire2 && player2.contains(pointOfTouch) {
        fireBullet2()
        // disable firing temporarily
        allowsFire2 = false
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + minFireDelay) { 
           allowsFire2 = true
        }
    }

    if allowsFire3 && player3.contains(pointOfTouch) {
        fireBullet3()
        // disable firing temporarily
        allowsFire3 = false
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + minFireDelay) { 
           allowsFire3 = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since there are names "player1", "player2", etc, I take that to mean that there are 3 separate players and each one should be able to fire their gun independently, as outlined in my answer.

Comment: I was able to get it working appreciate the help from everybody :)

Answer (score 1):

Look up `Timer` (`NSTimer` in Swift 2 and Objective-C.)

The idea is as follows:

Have a `gunXEnabled` `Bool` for each player's gun. Set each `Bool` to true initially.

Have your `fireBullet1()` method check `gun1Enabled`. If false, do nothing.

If `gun1Enabled == true`, fire the gun, set `gun1Enabled = false`, and start a timer that will re-enable the gun once it fires:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: false) {
  (timer) -> Void) in
  gun1Enabled = true
}
```

I gave you the unfamiliar part, creating the timer. See if you can work out the rest, and if not, post your code with info about what's not working.